# Does the non-parallel sample sort have the same complexity as quick sort?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, quicksort, divide-and-conquer

According to wikipedia and other resources, quick sort happens to be a special case of sample sort, because we always choose 1 partitioning item, put it in it's place and continue the sort, so quick sort is sample sort, where m (the number of partitioning items at each step) is 1. **So, my question is, for 1 < m < n does it have the same complexity as quick sort when it's not parallel?**

The following is the algorithm for sample sort described on wikipedia.

**1) Find splitters, values that break up the data into buckets, by sampling the data.**

**2) Use the sorted splitters to define buckets and place data in appropriate buckets.**

**3) Sort each of the buckets.**

I am not exactly sure I understand this algorithm correctly, but I think we first find the partitioning item, put it in it's place and then look to the left and to the right to find more partitioning items there, and then recursively call the same function to partition each one of those m samples into m samples again, **am I right?** Because if so, it seems that sample sort performs the same as quick sort because it simply does the same thing, except half of it iteratively (when looking for splitters) and half of it recursively.

Answer (score 0):

They will have different complexity. When *m > 1*, their running would be approximate to CNlog<sub>m+1</sub>N. The constant C will be large enough to make it slower than ordinary QuickSort because there is no known algorithm to partition list into *m + 1* buckets as efficiency  as partition list into two buckets.

For example, normal QuickSort would takes O(N) to partition the list into two sub array. Assuming in best case, QuickSort perfectly choose value that split list into two buckets of the same size.

> C<sub>n</sub> = 2C<sub>n/2</sub> + n  = nlog<sub>2</sub>n

Let assume that m = 2 that's mean we need to partition the list into three sub array. Let assuming that in best case, we can perfectly choose  values that split the list into three buckets of the same size. However, let's say the cost of partition is O(3N).

> C<sub>n</sub> = 3C<sub>n/3</sub> + 3n  = 3nlog<sub>3</sub>n

As you can see

> 3nlog<sub>3</sub>n > nlog<sub>2</sub>n.

Comment: But how do we partition it? I haven't seen a properly described algorithm anywhere. And why is C_n = 3C_n/3 + 3n When m = 2? I think you meant 3C_n/3 + 2n? That way we get 2Nlog_3(N), but that doesn't change anything still

Comment: @paulpaul1076, I am assuming that to partition for m = 2 would costs roughly O(3N). You can achieve O(3N) by first count number of element that is smaller than first and second splitter. Let called the position of the splitter P(0) and P(1). Counting value that is smaller than those two takes O(N). Then, divide the list into 3 buckets takes O(2N) because you need to copy the list into temporary list. Then, anything that is smaller than first value will be place in position below P(0) and anything that is smaller than second value will be place position below P(1).

Comment: @paulpaul1076, although, you can come up with algorithm that takes O(2N) to partition into 3 buckets, it will takes 2Nlog_3(N) which is greater than Nlog_2(N) because limit 2Nlog_3(N)/Nlog_2(N) as N approach infinite is > 1.